# Regex to return the word before the match

Tags: c#, regex

I've been trying to extract the word before the match. For example, I have the following sentence:

"**Allatoona was a town located in extreme southeastern Bartow County, Georgia.**"

I want to extract the word before "Bartow".

I've tried the following regex to extract that word:

```
\w\sCounty,
```

What I get returned is "w County" when what I wanted is just the word Bartow.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean the word before "County", which happens to be "Bartow".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use this regex with a lookahead to find word before `County`:

```
\w+(?=\s+County)
```

`(?=\s+County)` is a positive lookahead that asserts presence of 1 or more whitespaces followed by word `County` ahead of current match.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/igjCuo/1)

If you want to avoid lookahead then you can use a capture group:

```
(\w+)\s+County
```

and extract captured group #1 from match result.

Answer (score 3):

Your `\w\sCounty,` regex returns `w County` because `\w` matches a *single* character that is either a letter, digit, or `_`. It does not match a *whole word*.

To match 1 or more symbols, you need to use a `+` *quantifier* and to capture the part you need to extract you can rely on *capturing groups*, `(...)`.

So, you can fix your pattern by mere replacing `\w` with `(\w+)` and then, after getting a match, access the `Match.Groups[1].Value`.

However, if the county name contains a non-word symbol, like a hyphen, `\w+` won't match it. A `\S+` matching 1 or more *non-whitespace symbols* might turn out a better option in that case.

See a [C# demo](http://ideone.com/zQImkY):

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(\S+)\s+County");
if (m.Success) 
{
     Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);  
}
```

See a [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2BCounty&i=Allatoona%20was%20a%20town%20located%20in%20extreme%20southeastern%20Bartow%20County%2C%20Georgia.).[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find the word before Country

**([\w]*.?\s+).?County**

- The **[\w]*** match any characters any times
- the **.?** is if maybe there is a especial character in the sentences like (,.!)
- and the **\s+** for the banks spaces ( work if there is a double blank space in the sentence)
- .? before Country if maybe a special character is placed there

If you want to find more than one word just add {n} after like this **([\w]*.?\s+){3}.?County**

Answer (score 0):

This simply works for me. Not one character, but any long words before County.

```
(\w.*.?\s+).?County
```