# How to extract the word before a certain word in a string?

Tags: r, string, dplyr, stringr

I have a data frame where each row of the column 'leg_activity' is a string of comma-separated words:

```
structure(list(id = c("100", "100060", "100073", "100098", "100102", 
"100104", "100125", "100128", "100149", "100217", "100220", "100271", 
"100464", "100465", "100520", "100607", "100653", "100745", "100757", 
"100760"), leg_activity = c("home", "home, car, work, car, leisure, car, other, car, leisure, car, work, car, shop, car, home", 
"home, walk, leisure, walk, leisure, walk, home", "home, car, other, car, shop, car, other, car, home", 
"home, car, work, car, home, car, home", "home", "home, walk, education, walk, home", 
"home, car, other, car, work, car, shop, car, shop, car, home", 
"home, car, shop, car, work, car, home", "home, bike, leisure, bike, home", 
"home, walk, shop, walk, home", "home, pt, leisure, car, leisure, pt, home", 
"home, car, education, car, home", "home, car, leisure, car, home", 
"home, walk, home, walk, shop, walk, home", "home, pt, work, walk, leisure, walk, work, pt, home", 
"home, pt, leisure, walk, leisure, walk, home", "home, walk, home, bike, shop, bike, home", 
"home, pt, work, pt, home, walk, work, walk, home", "home")), row.names = c(2L, 
15L, 20L, 24L, 31L, 33L, 40L, 43L, 48L, 70L, 73L, 93L, 147L, 
148L, 156L, 174L, 188L, 213L, 214L, 220L), class = "data.frame")
```

In each string, I want to extract the word that appears before the word `work`. `work` can appear multiple times and the preceeding word needs to be extracted or counted for each time.

Eventually, I am interested to count how frequently which word appears before `work` over the entire df.

What I have tried:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df%>%
  separate_rows(leg_activity, sep = "work, ") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = leg_activity)
```

Clearly, this does not lead to the result but only separates the df into columns. So perhaps another approach is more appropriate.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to return the word before the match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44611824/regex-to-return-the-word-before-the-match)

Comment: @Limey the problem seems to be the same, yes. But I dont know C#. I'm looking for a solution in R

Comment: My bad, I missed the c-sharp tag.  Nonetheless, regexes are the way to go.  Take a look at the `stringr` package.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012861/regex-in-r-matching-the-string-before-a-sequence-of-characters) looks mofre relevant. ;)

Comment: `gsub('(\\w+,)(?=\\s*work)|.', '\\1', df$leg_activity, perl = TRUE)` then you can split into columns based on `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a slightly smaller data set to make it easier to track the result of the code:

```
d = data.frame(id = 1:3, leg = c("home",
                                 "work, R, eat, work",
                                 "eat, work, R, work"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Split the strings (`strsplit`) on `", "`. Loop over the resulting list (`lapply`). Get indices of "work" (`which(x == "work")`), get the previous index (`-1`). Use `pmax` to get an empty vector if "work" is the first word. Index the words (`x[<the-index>]`). Unlist and count items (`table(unlist(...`).

```
table(unlist(lapply(strsplit(d$leg, ", "), function(x) x[pmax(0, which(x == "work") - 1)])))
# eat   R 
#   2   1
```

Given "*Eventually, I am interested to count how frequently which word appears before work over the entire df.*", it seems like grouping is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `separate_rows` just with comma to get your words on different rows. Then, after grouping by `id` you can `filter` rows where the following/lead row has "work"?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(leg_activity, sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(leg_activity = trimws(leg_activity)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(lead(leg_activity) == "work") %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  id     count
  <chr>  <int>
1 100060     2
2 100102     1
3 100128     1
4 100149     1
5 100607     2
6 100757     2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
WantedStrings <- sub(", work","",str_extract_all(df$leg_activity, "\\w+, work",simplify=T))
WantedStrings <- WantedStrings[WantedStrings != ""]

table(WantedStrings)


WantedStrings
 car   pt walk 
   5    2    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Base R one liner:

```
   table(unlist(strsplit(gsub("(\\w+\\,)\\s*(work\\,)", "\\1", 
                           lst$leg_activity), ", ")))
```